# upower show energy-full-design: 0 Wh on new battery after full discharge

Tags: battery

I bought new battery (not oryginal - Green Cell with 9 samsung cells - 87Wh capacity) for Dell Vostro 3560.
First 5 cycles I charge bettery to 100% and discharged to about 3-5% (this took about 4-5h). But 6 cycle was discharging until laptop switch off (I wanted to test battery).
After laptop switch off I plug in power supply and leave to charge fully.
When I switch on laptop I saw (image below).

[View from power manager in Kubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTrE5.png)

Even battery is fully charged laptop is switching off immediately (on battery). I need to disable power manager to avoid this. Then laptop work on this battery 4 to 5h, but all this
time I see that battery is 0%

```
Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
root@phantom:~# uname -a
Linux phantom 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@phantom:~# upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               Dynapack
  model:                DELL YJNKK18C
  serial:               0001
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 08 Oct 2016 02:38:13 PM CEST (76 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              89.27 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         89.27 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         3.892 W
    voltage:             12.679 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1475930293  3.892   charging
```

I notice that energy-full-design is 0 Wh. Before "full discharge" this was 87.92 Wh,
and the percentage is 0%.
I also notice that

```
root@phantom:~# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full
0
root@phantom:~# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design 
86580000
root@phantom:~# cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now 
89270000
```

Here energy_full_design is 86580000 instead of 0, while upower show 0 Wh.
I try too:

```
root@phantom:/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1# chmod 644 energy_full
root@phantom:/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1# ls -l | grep energy_full
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct  8 14:42 energy_full
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct  8 14:37 energy_full_design
root@phantom:/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1# cat energy_full_design > energy_full
cat: write error: No such device
```

I also try:

```
root@phantom:~# rm /var/lib/upower/*
```

and restart upowerd with no luck.

And:

```
apt-get remove --purge upower; apt-get autoremove; apt-get install upower
```

Also no luck.

Anyway computer is working up to 5h on battery so cells are ok.

1. It is a problem with battery build in controller or some subsystem in ubuntu/kubuntu - like upower ?
2. Can I set somehow energy-full-design from hand ?
   Or any other workaround to cheat upower about energy-full-design ?
3. Why upower show energy-full-design: 0 Wh but /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design is 86580000 ?